# UI Not Displaying Properly in Quarkus App with OptaPlanner Integration

Tags: javascript

I'm working on a project based on a tutorial from an OptaPlanner video, where I'm building a Quarkus application with OptaPlanner integration. I've copied the code from their Git repository, but I'm encountering an issue where the UI is not displaying properly. Specifically, only the data is being shown, but the UI components are not rendering correctly. I've checked the dependencies, configurations, and code for errors, but I'm still unable to resolve the issue. Can someone provide guidance on how to troubleshoot and fix this problem to ensure that the UI displays properly in my Quarkus application with OptaPlanner integration? Any insights or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

I've tried to match the dependencies gievn to thier git files only for UI and Java file which I used for backend that I wrote it on my own but there's not showing any kind of error only the problem is that, that the UI is not working and expect it to show the data which I input shows.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.